# i want to sum all digit in a number

Tags: php, numbers, addition, digit

i want to add all digit in a number and if it is 11,22 then i want to display only 11 or 22 else i want to make it a single digit.
example 30=3+0=3
28=2+8=10=1+0=1

i just made a codebut it have an error
please help.

```
<?php
$day = 17;  
$month = 8;   
$year = 1993;    

function sumday($day)   
{   
     if ($day == 11)    
    {   
        $sday = 11;   
    }    
    elseif ($day == 22)     
    {    
        $sday = 22;   
    }   
    elseif ($day == 29)    
    {   
        $sday = 11;   
    }    
    else    
        {   
             do {    
            $nday = $day . "";    
            $sday = 0;    
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($nday); ++$i)   
            {    
                $sday += $nday[$i];    
            }    
            while ($sday <=9);    

} 

return $sday;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, here's my guess at what I interpreted your text as saying. https://eval.in/496369

Comment: Isn't the test in the `while` backwards? You want to keep repeating when the result is bigger than 9, don't you?

Comment: You need to set `$nday` to `$sday` before repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`please refer to unnikked's answer`, that's a good answer.
And here's the full code, combined with unnikked's answer

```
<?php
$day = 17;  
$month = 8;   
$year = 1993;    

function sumday($day)   
{   
     if ($day == 11)    
    {   
        $sday = 11;   
    }    
    elseif ($day == 22)     
    {    
        $sday = 22;   
    }   
    elseif ($day == 29)    
    {   
        $sday = 11;   
    }    
    else{  
        $sday = $day;
        do {    
             $sday = $sday % 10 + floor($sday/10);
        } while ($sday >= 10); 
    }
return $sday;
}

?>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to return the sum if it's 11,22,33 in the while loop, then put the conditions in the while loop rather than using if else condition, it's much simpler tho :)

```
function sumday($day)   
{   
    $sday = $day;
    while ($sday >= 10 && $sday != 11 && $sday != 22 && $sday != 29){
        $sday = $sday % 10 + floor($sday/10);
    }
return $sday;
}
```

**EDIT:** here's the logic that can split the day and sum them

```
function sumday($day)   
{   
    $sday = $day;
    $arrday = str_split($sday); // split the day into array
    $sumarrday = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen((string)$sday); $i++){
        $sumarrday = $sumarrday + $arrday[$i]; // sum the day from the array
    }
    $sday = $sumarrday; 
    // here you can modify the condition of while statement for your needs
    // for example, if you want to return 29 when 29 shows up, add this to your condition, && $sday != 29
    while ($sday >= 10){
        $sday = $sday % 10 + floor($sday/10);
    }   
    return $sday;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to return  the sum if it is 11,22 or 33 in the do while loop?

Comment: sir if my $day == 994 then also i want to exit from the loop and disply 22 like 8885> 8+8+8+5=29> 2+9=11 ; i want to disply 11

Comment: hi, i thought the $day only contains 2 digit, because it's "day". haha. in that case, you need to add different logic. I'll help you later, cause I'm still working now :).

Comment: u r rit but i want to sum year also by same function. if you have time kindly help me. thanks for your quick help

Comment: ahh i see, okay, i'll help you later, after my office hour :)

Comment: hi @user752826, as promised, see my edited post above

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would suggest you to learn to separate the tasks that a function do.

You ask to sum up the digits of a number, you may first create a function called `sum_digits`

```
<?php

function sum_digits($num) {
    if ($num < 10) 
        return $num;
    return $num % 10 + sum_digits(floor($num/10));
}
```

and then via conditional do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. im new to php just started learning.

Comment: is it possible to return the sum if it is 11,22 or 33 in the do while loop?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
else {   
     $nday = $day . "";   //moved out wrom loop
     do {   
        $sday = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($nday); ++$i)   
        {    
            $sday += $nday[$i];    
        } 
        $nday = $sday . ""; // you forget this line   
        while ($sday <=9);    

}
```